# python try except in socket not working

Tags: python, sockets, try-catch, except

My Code is:

```
usso = socket.gethostbyname("site.com")
try:
    usso
except socket.gaierror:
    uss = 0
else:
    uss = 1
if uss == 1:
    print ("Site Is True")
elif uss == 0:
    print ("Site Is Wrong")
```

but except not working and result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
    usso = socket.gethostbyname("site.com")
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

What is the Problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the statements that can cause exception into try catch block. In the original code the the exception occurred before the try catch block i.e. on first line.

Try this

```
try:
    usso = socket.gethostbyname("site.com")
except socket.gaierror:
    uss = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code not include in "try" block.
It should be:

```
try:
    usso = socket.gethostbyname("site.com")
except socket.gaierror:
    print 'yolos'
```